# How do you calculate the energy stored in a gravitational wave?

Tags: gravitational-waves

If you had an oscillating boson in a vacuum with an observer some distance away, how would you calculate the energy that the observer receives or loses as a result of experiencing a gravitational wave?

Comment: Your title and body are asking two quite different questions. A detector doesn’t absorb all of the energy that passes through.

Comment: Are you aware that we can’t detect gravitational waves from individual elementary particles? We can barely detect them from black holes and neutron stars.

Comment: Related: [How much energy does the Earth absorb when a gravitational wave passes through it?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/237168/how-much-energy-does-the-earth-absorb-when-a-gravitational-wave-passes-through-i)

Comment: Also, [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/412990/123208) shows how to calculate the gravitational energy emitted by a 2 body orbital system.

Comment: I'm not really asking for a practical application just theoretically for a particle and observer.